# Nginx Ingress showing 404 Not Found

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have installed `Nginx Ingress Controller` by using this [Link](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/installation-with-manifests/)

From the above link. i have executed the below commands.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress.git --branch v2.4.2
$ cd kubernetes-ingress/deployments

$ kubectl apply -f common/ns-and-sa.yaml
$ kubectl apply -f rbac/rbac.yaml

$ kubectl apply -f common/default-server-secret.yaml

$ kubectl apply -f common/nginx-config.yaml
$ kubectl apply -f common/ingress-class.yaml

$ kubectl apply -f common/crds/k8s.nginx.org_virtualservers.yaml
$ kubectl apply -f common/crds/k8s.nginx.org_virtualserverroutes.yaml
$ kubectl apply -f common/crds/k8s.nginx.org_transportservers.yaml
$ kubectl apply -f common/crds/k8s.nginx.org_policies.yaml

$ kubectl apply -f common/crds/k8s.nginx.org_globalconfigurations.yaml

$ kubectl apply -f daemon-set/nginx-ingress.yaml
```

It is runs as a daemon set,

```
$ kubectl get all -n nginx-ingress -o wide
NAME                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP           NODE        NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
pod/nginx-ingress-mfnk8   1/1     Running   0          18h   10.244.2.8   worker-3    <none>           <none>
pod/nginx-ingress-n4b79   1/1     Running   0          18h   10.244.1.6   worker-2    <none>           <none>
pod/nginx-ingress-ndtkw   1/1     Running   0          18h   10.244.3.5   worker-4    <none>           <none>

NAME                           DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR   AGE   CONTAINERS      IMAGES                      SELECTOR
daemonset.apps/nginx-ingress   3         3         3       3            3           <none>          18h   nginx-ingress   nginx/nginx-ingress:2.4.2   app=nginx-ingress
```

```
$ kubectl logs nginx-ingress-n4b79 -n nginx-ingress
I0111 09:17:11.242514       1 flags.go:199] Starting NGINX Ingress Controller Version=2.4.2 PlusFlag=false
I0111 09:17:11.242568       1 flags.go:200] Commit=4252538e0d02dfd42cd3b35884cd5b50147814b7 Date=2022-11-30T14:54:40Z DirtyState=false Arch=linux/amd64 Go=go1.19.3
I0111 09:17:11.249520       1 main.go:214] Kubernetes version: 1.24.9
I0111 09:17:11.257785       1 main.go:341] Using nginx version: nginx/1.23.2
2023/01/11 09:17:11 [notice] 24#24: using the "epoll" event method
2023/01/11 09:17:11 [notice] 24#24: nginx/1.23.2
2023/01/11 09:17:11 [notice] 24#24: built by gcc 10.2.1 20210110 (Debian 10.2.1-6)
2023/01/11 09:17:11 [notice] 24#24: OS: Linux 5.4.0-132-generic
2023/01/11 09:17:11 [notice] 24#24: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1048576:1048576
2023/01/11 09:17:11 [notice] 24#24: start worker processes
2023/01/11 09:17:11 [notice] 24#24: start worker process 30
2023/01/11 09:17:11 [notice] 24#24: start worker process 31
2023/01/11 09:17:11 [notice] 24#24: start worker process 32
2023/01/11 09:17:11 [notice] 24#24: start worker process 33
2023/01/11 09:17:11 [notice] 24#24: start worker process 34
2023/01/11 09:17:11 [notice] 24#24: start worker process 35
2023/01/11 09:17:11 [notice] 24#24: start worker process 36
2023/01/11 09:17:11 [notice] 24#24: start worker process 37
2023/01/11 09:17:11 [notice] 24#24: start worker process 38
2023/01/11 09:17:11 [notice] 24#24: start worker process 39
2023/01/12 04:30:33 [notice] 24#24: signal 17 (SIGCHLD) received from 288
2023/01/12 04:30:33 [notice] 24#24: worker process 288 exited with code 0
2023/01/12 04:30:33 [notice] 24#24: worker process 282 exited with code 0
2023/01/12 04:30:33 [notice] 24#24: worker process 290 exited with code 0
2023/01/12 04:30:33 [notice] 24#24: worker process 304 exited with code 0
2023/01/12 04:30:33 [notice] 24#24: worker process 328 exited with code 0
2023/01/12 04:30:33 [notice] 24#24: worker process 315 exited with code 0
2023/01/12 04:30:33 [notice] 24#24: signal 29 (SIGIO) received
2023/01/12 04:30:33 [notice] 24#24: signal 17 (SIGCHLD) received from 290
```

When i tried to connect Nginx container using `http://{Worker-IP}`, Have tried with all three Worker-IPs. For all three it shows `404 Not Found` on browser.

Nginx container `Status` shows `Running` & `Ready` shows `(1/1)`. What could the problem? Also let me know Am i missing any additional installation commands?

```
$ kubectl get ingress --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE   NAME              CLASS    HOSTS                ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
jenkins     jenkins-ingress   <none>   jenkins.company.com             80      19h
```

```
$ kubectl get svc  --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME          TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE
default       kubernetes    ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP                  46h
jenkins       jenkins-svc   ClusterIP   10.103.54.142   <none>        80/TCP                   46h
kube-system   kube-dns      ClusterIP   10.96.0.10      <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   46h
```

Comment: are you trying wiht node port service or LB service type ? if node port append it behind the workerIP and did you created the ingress resource.

Comment: @Harsh Manvar - So i can't access my `nginx-ingress controller POD` with `http://{Worker-IP}`? I need to have `nginx resource file` to connect? To answer your question - Yes i have HA Proxy LB outside of my Kubernetes cluster. So in my application service side using `type: ClusterIP`.

Comment: which type your ingress controller service is ? check the svc type of nginx ingress controller and also share output of `kubectl get ingress --all-namespaces`

Comment: any which type your service is nginx ingress svc ?

Comment: i have Jenkins service. `kubectl get svc  --all-namespaces` result added.

Comment: `kubectl get svc --all-namespaces` try this and show ouptut

Comment: looks like there is not nginx ingress service for controller.

Comment: Yes was thinking even here `kubectl get all -n nginx-ingress -o wide`  output can't see Nginx ingress service. Any commands i missed as part of Nginx ingress installation?

Comment: there could be chances, let me check doc you followed once. trying on which cloud or minikube locally it is ?

Comment: `Kubernetes v1.24.9 `cluster (One master and three workers) bare metal based.

Comment: did you runt the step 4. Get Access to the Ingress Controller ? there is node port and LB service execution code.

Comment: 4.1 Create a Service for the Ingress Controller Pods 
   `Use a NodePort service.`
   ` Create a service with the type NodePort:`
    `$ kubectl create -f service/nodeport.yaml`
This step no i have not installed.

Comment: yes that's the main part to create the svc had doubt only as service missing.follow it please

Comment: Now it runs `nginx-ingress   nginx-ingress   NodePort    10.104.207.132   <none>        80:32460/TCP,443:31396/TCP   4s    app=nginx-ingress` but still i can't access my application using `http://jenkins.company.com/jenkins`

Comment: it won't like that way now set workerip in `/etc/hosts` and point it to jenkins.company.com and thn hit that with proper nodeport 31396 or 32460 and ingress.

Comment: `jenkins.company.com` already existing in `/etc/host `file of all (master & workers). My jenkins application service running as `type: ClusterIP` But `Ngnix ingress` service created as `type NodePort`

Comment: that's fine from where you are trying to access jenkins.company.com ?

Comment: Outside of cluster for example On my laptop.

Comment: and where is your master and worker running? your example my laptop can have access to worker IP ? can access it with IP or you are on some cloud and create multiple vms ? make sure local or laptop should be able to connect to workip, or your jenkin.<domain> should be proper in DNS which should be pointing to IP of LB if using it.

Comment: Master, Workers and LB are running separately on VMs. In Master, Worker, LB and my laptop i have added `jenkins.company.com` entry along with LB IP address in host file.

Comment: if your nginx ingress controller is svc nodeport how you got the LB IP or which one you are suing ? if it's node port use the workerIP in `/etc/hosts` use node port and try to access it will work. http://workerip:nodeport/<URL path> as you have already mapped workerIP to hosts file it will be like http://jenkin.company.com:nodeport

Comment: My jenkins application service runs as `type: ClusterIP` then nginx-ingress application service runs as `type: NodePort`, In my HAproxy LB added front and backend for my Kubernetes cluster (master & workers).

Comment: Basically i need to access my jenkins like `http://jenkins.company.com/jenkins` outside of cluster example on users systems.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58574104/kubernetes-nginx-ingress-controller-on-nodeport

Comment: @user4948798 Has your issue been resolved?

Comment: @Fariya Rahmat Not yet. Found that my HAproxy not forwarding the request to Kubernetes nginx ingress controller, which I'm trying to address it.